# First dynamically added component not getting styling from a class

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a big list of dynamically added components and all of them are getting styling from the css class except the first one. It's specifically a darkmode or litemode class that gets added depending on the if this.state.dark === true or not

here's the function that renders them

```
renderComponent(info) {
        return <Info isDark={this.isDark()} isHidden={this.state.hide === true} user={info} key={info} /> 
    }
```

and this is what calls that function

```
{info.map(this.renderComponent)}
```

css class that's not rendering on first component

```
.darkmode + .other-class {
    background-color: rgb(131, 21, 21);
}
```

I've tried conditionally rendering the page into a separate version with just darkmode and using the classes directly everywhere(ie there's no way they don't have the class).

In inspect element it says they have the class and even styling from a different area in the css is being applied. but the background stays transparent on just the first element.

I've also tried adding the class in the component itself and it's always the exact same result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKuMQ.png picture of the element not loading the css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/70ErG.png picture of element that is loading the css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a problem with your CSS selector.

The plus (+) sign select and style every element that is placed inmediately after the first element in your CSS selector.

[In W3School you can see this behaviour](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
.darkmode.Offline {
    background-color: rgb(131, 21, 21);
}
```